# Deleting list members by rule

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"d", "e", "x"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}
```

I would like to remove elements from this list if the following condition is met.

Compare adjacent members of the list.  If they are identical except for the third sub-element being "x", then delete the element that contains the "x"

This gives:

```
res = {{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i}}
```

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[Last@# == "x" &] @ lis, 
   Most[#] == Most[#2] && MemberQ[Last /@ {##}, "x"] &]
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}
> ```

**Update:** A more flexible approach using [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html) + [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = SequenceReplace[{OrderlessPatternSequence[
      p1 : {a___, _, b___}, {a___, "x", b___}]} :> p1];
```

***Examples:***

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"d", "e", "x"}, {"g", "h", "i"}};
lis2 = {{"a", "b", "c", "z"}, {"d", "e", "f", "z"}, {"d", "e", "x", "z"}, 
   {"g", "h", "i", "z"}, {"w", "x", "y", "z"}, {"w", "x", "x", "z"}};
lis3 = {{"a", "b", "c", "z"}, {"d", "e", "f", "z"}, {"d", "e", "x", "z"}, 
   {"g", "h", "i", "z"}, {"q", "r", "s", "t"}, {"q", "r", "x",  "t"}};

f @ lis
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}
> ```

```
f @ lis2
```

> ```
>  {{"a", "b", "c", "z"}, {"d", "e", "f", "z"},
>   {"g", "h", "i", "z"}, {"w", "x", "y", "z"}}
> ```

```
f @ lis3
```

> ```
>  {{"a", "b", "c", "z"}, {"d", "e", "f", "z"}, 
>   {"g", "h", "i", "z"}, {"q", "r", "s", "t"}}
> ```

Comment: Generalization: how would this work with a slightly different data set, where the marker for deletion isn't the last member of the list element: say, lis =lis = {{"a", "b", "c", "z"}, {"d", "e", "f", "z"}, {"d", "e", "x", 
   "z"}, {"g", "h", "i", "z"}, {"w", "x", "y", "z"}, {"w", "x", "x", 
   "z"}}

Comment: please ignore the above comment, the comment edit timed out before I finished my question..  Here is the correct comment:  Generalization : 
 how would this work with a slightly different data set, where the \
marker for deletion isn' t the last member of the list element : 
  say, {{"a", "b", "c", "z"}, {"d", "e", "f", "z"}, {"d", "e", "x", 
   "z"}, {"g", "h", "i", "z"}, {"q", "r", "s", "t"}, {"q", "r", "x", 
   "t"}} with the desired res to be : {{"a", "b", "c", "z"}, {"d", 
    "e", "f", "z"}, {"g", "h", "i", "z"}, {"q", "r", "s", "t"}}

Comment: @Suite401, maybe something like: `ClearAll[f]; f[p_] := DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[#[[p]] == "x" &]@#, Drop[#, {p}] == Drop[#2, {p}] && MemberQ[{##}[[All, p]], "x"] &] &;
f[3]@lis2`?

Comment: OK will give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

To do this via a rule substitution:

```
lis /. {a___, {b_, c_, d_}, {b_, c_, "x"}, e___} :> {a, {b, c, d}, e}
```

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}

This can fail if the `{b_, c_, "x"}` pattern occurs before its identical match, however. We can fix this by including the alternative, though it is a bit verbose to do so:

```
lis /. {a___, 
   Alternatives[PatternSequence[{b_, c_, d_}, {b_, c_, "x"}], 
    PatternSequence[{b_, c_, "x"}, {b_, c_, d_}]], 
   e___} :> {a, {b, c, d}, e}
```

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}

Also in the case that multiple matches are possible, `ReplaceRepeated` may be necessary:

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "x"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"d", "e", 
   "x"}, {"g", "h", "i"}};
lis //. {a___, 
   Alternatives[PatternSequence[{b_, c_, d_}, {b_, c_, "x"}], 
    PatternSequence[{b_, c_, "x"}, {b_, c_, d_}]], 
   e___} :> {a, {b, c, d}, e}
```

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `SequencePosition`

**Case 1:** The x-pattern only occurs after

```
list =
  {{"a", "b", "c"},
   {"d", "e", "f"}, {"d", "e", "x"},
   {"g", "h", "i"},
   {"p", "q", "f"}, {"p", "q", "x"}};

p = List @* Last /@ SequencePosition[list, {{a_, b_, _}, {a_, b_, "x"}}]
```

{{3}, {6}}

```
Delete[p] @ list
```

{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}, {"p", "q", "f"}}

**Case 2:** The x-pattern can occur before or after

```
list =
  {{"a", "b", "c"},
   {"d", "e", "f"}, {"d", "e", "x"},
   {"g", "h", "i"},
   {"p", "q", "x"}, {"p", "q", "f"}};

p = SequencePosition[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[{a_, b_, _}, {a_, b_, "x"}]}]
```

{{2, 3}, {5, 6}}

```
q = Intersection @@@ Transpose[{p, Position[list, "x"]}]
```

{{3}, {5}}

```
Delete[q] @ list
```

{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}, {"p", "q", "f"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 =
  {{"a", "b", "c"},
   {"d", "e", "f"}, {"d", "e", "x"},
   {"g", "h", "i"},
   {"p", "q", "f"}, {"p", "q", "x"}};

l2 =
  {{"a", "b", "c"},
   {"d", "e", "f"}, {"d", "e", "x"},
   {"g", "h", "i"},
   {"p", "q", "x"}, {"p", "q", "f"}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's examples and using `GroupBy` and `DeleteCases`:

```
Flatten[Values@GroupBy[l1, #[[1]] &, DeleteCases[#, {a__, "x"}] &], 1]

(*{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}, {"p", "q", "f"}}*)


Flatten[Values@GroupBy[l2, #[[1]] &, DeleteCases[#, {a__, "x"}] &], 1]

(*{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}, {"p", "q", "f"}}*)
```