# Deleting duplicated lists containing a placeholder

Tags: list-manipulation

Some time ago I asked the question about [Deleting list members by rule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255836/deleting-list-members-by-rule) and received a variety of responses.

I have a slightly different data set and here wish to delete list members whose third and fifth elements are "xx" but otherwise are identical to the other members of that element:

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, 
       {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"}, 
       {"a", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}, 
       {"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}};
```

to give:

```
res = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, 
       {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"},    
       {"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}}
```

Using @eyorble's suggestion, I tried:

```
lis /. {a___, 
Alternatives[
PatternSequence[{b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_}, {b_, c_, "xx", e_, "xx",
   g_}], PatternSequence[{b_, c_, "xx", e_, "xx", g_}, {b_, c_, 
  d_, e_, f_, g_}]], w___} :> {a, {b, c, d, e, f, g}, w}
```

...which fails.

Comment: A variation of the neat method given by @kglr (which also uses `MapAt` 'under the hood': `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Query[Thread[{3,5}->("xx"&)]]]@lis`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[MapAt["xx" &, {{3}, {5}}]] @ lis
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"},   
>  {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"},   
>  {"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}}
> ```

```
lis2 = Append[lis, {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}];

DeleteDuplicatesBy[MapAt["xx" &, {{3}, {5}}]] @ lis2
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"},   
>  {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"},   
>  {"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"},   
>  {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"}, 
      {"a", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}, {"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}, 
      {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}};

Values@GroupBy[lis, #[[1]] &, First] (*Edit*)

(*{{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"}, 
  {"o","p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}, {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}}*)
```

An example suggested by Eldo:

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", 
"m"}, {"a", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}, {"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", 
"t"}, {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}, {"z", "b", "xx", "d", 
"xx", "f"}};

Values@GroupBy[lis, #[[1]] &, First]

(*{{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"}, 
{"o","p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}, {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}}*)
```

Comment: The question is about deleting any duplicates but with the exception of "placeholder" positions 3, 5 as interpreted by @kglr. Initially, I misunderstood it, so I will delete the comment.

Comment: Thanks, mate! :-)

Comment: Does this function with `lis = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"}, {"a", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}, {"o", "p", "q", "r", "s",  "t"}, {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}, {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}} ?`

Comment: Thanks, @eldo! :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", 
    "m"}, {"a", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}, {"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", 
    "t"}, {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}};

comp = Complement[Range[6], {3, 5}]
First /@ GatherBy[lis, {#[[comp]] &}]
```

> {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"}, {"o",
> "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}, {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}}

---

**EDIT**

To make this edit more general, the addendum will use the following list that could contain more duplicated entries matching the placeholder pattern:

```
lis = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "g", "d", "m", 
    "f"}, {"g", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"}, {"a", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", 
    "f"}, {"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}, {"z", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", 
    "f"}};

GatherBy[lis, {#[[comp]] &}] /. {{k_List} :> 
   k, {g___, {_, _, "xx", _, "xx", _}, h___} -> Sequence @@ {g, h}}
```

> {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "g", "d", "m", "f"}, {"g",
> "h", "i", "j", "l", "m"}, {"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}, {"z",
> "b", "xx", "d", "xx", "f"}}

where unduplicated entries (even those containing "xx" are retained). Only the placeholder matching any duplicated entry is filtered out.